# Sybase iq cannot load table with datetime column

Tags: datetime, load, sap-iq

I'm trying to load table to a **sybase iq** database from a text file, and have a trouble loading datetime field... Always get error `data type conversion is not possible`. I tried a lot of ways in solving it...

- creating varchar field and converting it to data
- creating temp table and inserting values into my table from temp table using dateformat, cast, convert,
- load table table_name(
  datetime_column datetime('dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm-ss')
  ) from ...

Nothing helps. Any help? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution

```
load table table_name (
    temp_date         ' | ',
  --  dt               datetime column 
)
from file_name

---------------------------------------
set dateformat dmy;
update table_name set dt = temp_date          

ALTER TABLE table_name 
DROP temp_date
```